# How do I use torch's class system to create a custom class

Tags: lua, torch

I was attempting to follow the [torch documentation for utility functions](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/utility.md).

And I did the following:

```
Blah = torch.class('Blah')
function Blah:__init(); end
blah = Blah()
```

But I get the following error:

```
attempt to call global 'Blah' (a table value)
```

I was expecting the `__init()` function to somehow work via the `__call` metatable mechanism, but Blah doesn't even seem to have a metatable:

```
th> getmetatable(Blah) == nil
true
```

Maybe the documentation is out of date? But torch seems to be creating plenty of classes this way internally.

I just updated to the latest torch, so I know it's not my torch version is too old...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
do
 local Blah = torch.class('Blah')
 function Blah:__init() end
end

blah = Blah()
```

Comment: Doh! So torch installs the symbol and then I'm overwriting it with the return value from `torch.class`.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You need:

`local Blah = torch.class('Blah')`

**2.** You need use:

```
do 
end
```

[lexical scoping](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ScopeTutorial), if you want to call `class 'Blah'` from the **same** module.
But if you call it from an **other** module - as we mostly do with a class -, we don't need use `do-end` [lexical scoping](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ScopeTutorial).

So if your module's purpose is just declaring a torch type class and then using it several time from other modules, you just need declare as `local` as above in the section **1.** and you don't need (but you **can**) **do-end** [lexical scoping](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ScopeTutorial).

Actually [torch documentation](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/utility.md) remark:

```
-- for naming convenience
```

is a bit misleading here, I guess.